# How to list files in linux shell using `ls` as they are listed in the corresponding folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem. When I use only `ls` command in the shell my files are listed as following (weird):

```
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 166 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 16 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 167 [720p].mkv
```

When I open my folder though, the files are listed like this (preferred):

```
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 16 [720p].mkv
...
...
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 166 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 167 [720p].mkv
```

How can I use the `ls` command to list the files in the shell exactly as in the corresponding folder. In the folder it is ordered "By Name".

When I type `ls -v` the list is as following:

```
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 11 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 12 [720p].mkv
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 13 [720p].mkv
...
...
[HorribleSubs] Fairy Tail - 175 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 01  [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 02 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 03 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 04 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 05 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 06 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 07 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 08 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 09 [720p].mkv
[Horriblesubs] Fairy Tail - 10 [720p].mkv
```

Comment: No need of python tag.

Comment: @Kris what if you run `\ls`? (Note the backslash)

Comment: I don't see that behavior; `ls` with no options prints `file16.txt  file166.txt  file167.txt`. Please update your question to show us the *exact* names of all the files in the directory and the *exact* output of `ls`.

Comment: @dogbane `\ls` gave me the same list as `ls`

Comment: @Keith Thompson I really don't know why it is ordering the files like this. That's why I'm asking here ;)

Comment: What does `type ls` print? And `locale`, particularly the value of `LC_COLLATE`?

Comment: ls is hashed (/usr/bin/ls), LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sort utility the user also has the option of specifying a starting column that is to be used for the sorting. So this command:

```
ls | sort -k 1.5n
```

Will sort using the `1st` column and the starting at the `5th` field. Assuming your files all start with the word `file`, this should use the number after that word  to sort in natural order

Output:

```
file01.txt
file11.txt
file16.txt
file116.txt
file167.txt
```

For your new case (Fairy Tail - # [720p].mkv...), try this command:

```
ls | sort -k4n
```

Comment: I think the main problem here is that I have numbers with 2 and 3 digits. All I want is the list to be ordered right from 1 to 175 starting with the lowest number and ending with the highest.

Comment: What output do you get when you run the above command? Remember that the `1.5` in the command means `column 1, field 5` So make sure yo adjust it accordingly if you are using it with the files you mentioned above

Comment: I get wrong list. It jumps from file09 to file100. There is also file106, file10, file107. File10 between the other files.

Comment: `ls | sort -k4n` isn't working either. Is there no way to just display the order of the folder in the shell?

Comment: YES I could solve it. It was `ls | sort -k5n`. You were pretty close. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls -v` for "natural sorting"

From the man page:

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: This works just almost. When I use `ls -v` the list starts with file11.txt up to file175.txt and then ends with file01.txt, file02.txt up to file10.txt

Answer (score 0):

you could always pipe the output of any command to the UNIX `sort` utility, and sort it however you'd like.  For instance:

```
% ls | sort 
file16.txt
file166.txt
file167.txt
```